# What tools are used to design and 'program' shape-memory polymers?

Tags: materials, material-science, software

I've been reading about shape-memory polymers. However, it is not clear to me what tools could be used to design the ultimate shape (the shape one obtains after applying for example electricity or light)?
What tools are used to design these shapes (software, methods, apparatus)?
Also, it seems to be the case that SMPs could be reprogrammed. What tools do exist for these tasks?

Comment: Is that the mattress that says « oh dear, not another fat one? »?

Comment: What do you mean by "tools" exactly? Do you mean methods or actual apparatus? Because for "reprogrammable" things it probably involves something to put the object under stress while applying whatever phenomena it is that is used to activate it. For sample, for nitinol which is not a SMP but an shape memory alloy, you apply a stress under heat. I would expect a specialized apparatus and/or fixture for each particular form, not a generalized one

Comment: @DKNguyen As I am new to this kind of materials, I didn't have something more differentiated in mind, when I wrote "tools". It's interesting to know about both methods and apparatus, if this question can accommodate that.